# Repositories reeplacement in a Symfony project configured with DBAL

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, dbal

I'm working in a project in Symfony 3.0.1 that use five databases with DBAL as data access layer. I always worked in Symfony with ORM and I always used the next MVC model:

### Data access:

CONTROLLER -> REPOSITORY (the queries goes here) -> ENTITY

### Display results:

CONTROLLER -> render($view,$params) -> VIEW

This model allow short and simple controllers, but now I'm using DBAL so I can't use repositories.

**The question is:**

How can I achieve a similar model by using DBAL? In others words, Where should I put the queries?

Should I use services instead of repositories?

**Note:** I only use the select statement in that databases.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an ORM in order to use entities.
Likewise, you do not need Doctrine to be able to build repositories once a repository is a implementation of design pattern:

**Repository**

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a
>   collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.
>   [Read more](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

Even though you can't use Doctrine ORM you still can to design POPO classes against an abstract model class or/and model interface.
You could inject DBAL Connection object for each model/entity via construct or setter method. After creating repo classes is easy. Returning collection objects, hydrating items or using raw arrays is up to you.

### Edit #1

I have added a real worl exemple I have used in the past (few years ago), look:

https://github.com/felipsmartins/misc-and-code-snippets/tree/master/php/model-exemple/src/AppBundle/Model

### Edit #2

Regarding services, it would much better if there is specialized and well defined models (as opposed to [Anemic Models](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)) working together inside a service which coordinates the whole transaction, in this case it would be what we know by **Unit of Work** (see [Unit of Work Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it wrong if I put the queries inside symfony services?

Comment: @EmilianoSangoi Not, isn't, absolutely! However it would much better if have specialized models working together inside a service which coordinates the whole transaction, in this case it would be what we know by Unit of Work (see [Unit of Work Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html))

Comment: I only use selects statement with this databases (The system I am working on only fetch data from this five databases), so I am looking for the best place to put the queries. Perhaps a implementation of the Repository pattern is not necesary but I will keep it in mind.

Comment: Is the design pattern object (DAO) another option?

Comment: @EmilianoSangoi It depends on! Maybe you want take a look this link: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220909/service-layer-vs-dao-why-both .

Comment: Also, if the system is intended to fetch data only, it's okay on creating model objects and that objects being services too, at the same time.